# Check array values in another array variable

Tags: php

I have 2 php array variables. Variables like below.

```
$arrIntPropertyIds = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$arrIntRequestPropertyIds = [ 3, 5, 7];`
```

I want to check whether values of `$arrIntRequestPropertyIds` are in `$arrIntPropertyIds` without loop.

So I tried like below.

```
if( count(array_diff($arrIntPropertyIds,$arrIntRequestPropertyIds))==0 ) {
    echo 'invalid property Id'; 
} else { 
    echo 'Valid property Id'; 
}
```

If all OR any of the value OR atleast 1 value is/are there in first array then it should show message 'invalid'.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the order in which you present the arrays to the `array_diff()` function and then change the if accordingly

```
$arrIntPropertyIds = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$arrIntRequestPropertyIds = [ 3, 5, 7];


if( count(array_diff($arrIntRequestPropertyIds, $arrIntPropertyIds))==0 ) {
    echo 'Valid property Id'; 
} else { 
    echo 'invalid property Id'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php). Simplest way to check this would be the following code

```
$containsValues = !array_diff($arrIntRequestPropertyIds, $arrIntPropertyIds);
```

Would return true or false

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arrIntPropertyIds = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$arrIntRequestPropertyIds = [ 3, 5, 7];

$intersect = count(array_intersect($arrIntPropertyIds, $arrIntRequestPropertyIds));

if ($intersect == count($arrIntRequestPropertyIds)) {
    echo '$arrIntPropertyIds include all of $arrIntRequestPropertyIds';
} elseif ($intersect > 0) {
    echo '$arrIntPropertyIds include part of $arrIntRequestPropertyIds';
} else {
    echo '$arrIntPropertyIds not include any of $arrIntRequestPropertyIds';
}
```

[run PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/0d68ed5d50f0fdf3b5ab6f2cfc20efb5/)